# Python: List Comprehensions vs. map

Tags: python, performance

Referring to this [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) question, can someone explain why List Comprehensions gives better results over `map` when list comprehension does not call a function, even when there is no lambda function in the `map` but gives the worst result when calling a function?

```
import timeit

print timeit.Timer('''[i**2 for i in xrange(100)]''').timeit(number = 100000)

print timeit.Timer('''map(lambda i: i**2, xrange(100))''').timeit(number = 100000)

print timeit.Timer(setup="""def my_pow(i):
    return i**2
""",stmt="""map(my_pow, xrange(100))""").timeit(number = 100000)

print timeit.Timer(setup="""def my_pow(i):
    return i**2
""",stmt='''[my_pow(i) for i in xrange(100)]''').timeit(number = 100000)
```

results:

```
1.03697046805 <-- list comprehension without function call
1.96599485313 <-- map with lambda function
1.92951520483 <-- map with function call
2.23419570042 <-- list comprehension with function call
```

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the function called in `map` is a lambda or a regular function, the overhead is still there. No idea why a list comprehension *with* a function call would be slower than `map()` though.

Comment: @millimoose but the lambda function gets declared for each itetaration, does this make any change?

Comment: @zenpoy: Function call arguments are evaluated before the function is called, so the function is declared only once.

Comment: cannot delete comments on my phine :(

Comment: @SvenMarnach i think he/she's talking about `my_pow` definition being interpreted only once for the whole timeit execution (in setup) and lambda being defined for each iteration. It's a valid question, and  lambda probably contributes to it's version being slightly slower.

Comment: @soulcheck Well, it's easy to just do `Timeit('lambda i: i**2')…` and compare. On my machine, it amounts to 0.67% of the time the map takes to run, which indicates that parsing that little code is negligible overhead compared to the rest.

Comment: @millimoose well one could say that difference between map-with-lambda and map-with-function-call is negligible in the OP's question too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All your timing results can be explained by theses facts:

1. CPython has a rather high function call overhead.
2. `map(f, it)` is slightly faster than `[f(x) for x in it]`.

The first version of your code does not define a function at all, so there is no function call overhead.  The second version needs to define a function, ,so there is function call overhead in every iteration.  The third version is completely equivalent to the second one – functions and lambda expressions are the same thing.  And the last version is even slower according to fact 2.

Comment: I can think of two possible reasons for fact (2): `map`'s loop takes place directly in C and so has slightly less overhead in the looping, and the reference to name `f` only needs to be resolved once for `map` but on each iteration for the list comprehension. The second feels more important to me, but any way to tell which one contributes more?

Comment: @Dougal: This is not the first time someone mention the loop taking place in C, but I never found a reference or something to substain that it should be faster.

Comment: @RikPoggi I tried checking the Python sources, and `map` in 3.x actually returns an iterator, and works on using the arguments' iterators, which makes that theory pretty unlikely. There might still be some savings from all of these being C-based, but there is no mythical "loop in C". It might be interesting (if not conclusive of anything) to compare the performance of 2.x and 3.x in this regard actually.

Comment: @millimoose: Things like "the loop is entirely done in C" usually mean that no Python byte-code evaluation is necessary to perform the loop.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Fair enough, but would that distinction make a significant difference? The runtime still has to deal with all the overhead of manipulating the interpreter state; it doesn't seem to me that bytecode dispatch in and of itself would be the main contributor to the slowdown.

Comment: @millimoose: It's hard to tell if this is a meaningful distinction.  I don't think there are any general rules here.  When performance really matters, you have to measure anyway in the end.

Comment: @SvenMarnach What I'm trying to say is more that it's a misleading phrasing that leads people to imagine what really goes on is that there's some piece of C code that goes more or less `for (int i = 0; i < len(it); i++) { f(it[i]); }` when that's not really the case. It'd be more accurate to say that what's fast is iterating over collections that have iterators implemented in C because you get to cut through a bunch of overhead that's not necessarily related to looping. (Like the function call you mention in your answer and name lookup that Dougal mentioned.)

Comment: @millimoose: Well, I certainly don't have such misconceptions, and I think I agree with everything you said.  I just wanted to clarify what people usually mean when saying "this loop is entirely in C code".  (By "people" I mean people familiar with the CPython source code.)