# Performance of loops, list comprehensions and maps in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, benchmarking

How is it possible to properly compare performance of for loops, list comprehensions and maps in Python 3.6?

In the code below, plain old for loops perform quite well (I used `list()` to get values from generators). Am I doing something wrong here? The results are in stark contrast to the [discussion on Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map).

```
import timeit

code_for = """
for i in range(1000):
    hex(i)
"""

code_map = """
list(map(hex, range(1000)))
"""

code_map_lambda = """
list(map(lambda x: hex(x), range(1000)))
"""

code_list_comprehension = """
[hex(x) for x in range(1000)]
"""

print(timeit.timeit(code_for, number=10000))
# 1.1155821208376437

print(timeit.timeit(code_map, number=10000))
# 0.8820606248918921

print(timeit.timeit(code_map_lambda, number=10000))
# 1.7510833400301635

print(timeit.timeit(code_list_comprehension, number=10000))
# 1.1798800542019308
```

UPDATE: Adding elements to a list in `code_for`

```
code_for_2 = """
a = [0] * 1000
for i in range(1000):
    a[i] = hex(i)
"""
# 1.243549756007269

code_for_3 = """
a = []
for i in range(1000):
    a.append(hex(i))
"""
# 1.5462996119167656
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few pointers:

1. Wrap your code in functions for clarity.
2. You are missing list creation and appends in `code_for`. This is the bulk of the cost of using an explicit `for` loop.
3. You can then use `timeit`, or if you have Jupyter notebook, the magic `%timeit` command.

As below, `map` without `lambda` performs best, which makes sense since `hex` is a built-in. See [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) for more details.

```
def code_for(n):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        res.append(hex(i))
    return res

def code_map(n):
    return list(map(hex, range(n)))

def code_map_lambda(n):
    return list(map(lambda x: hex(x), range(n)))

def code_list_comprehension(n):
    return [hex(x) for x in range(n)]

%timeit code_for(10000)                 # 3.19 ms per loop
%timeit code_map(10000)                 # 1.69 ms per loop
%timeit code_map_lambda(10000)          # 3.06 ms per loop
%timeit code_list_comprehension(10000)  # 2.27 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Could you please clarify why `list(map(...))` is equivalent to `append()` rather than to setting values in a preallocated list?

Comment: They are certainly not *equivalent* (hence the performance difference). But the results are identical because they both output lists. If you don't use `list.append`, `code_for` will return nothing, it'll apply `hex` to each item but the results will be forever lost. You should look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) for general details on these performance differences.

Comment: I'm asking, because with a preallocated list the results of `code_for` are the same as without putting elements to a list at all. `append()` is slower, of course.

Comment: @Konstantin, Sorry, I don't understand. Why assume lists are pre-allocated with any of these methods?

Comment: Please refer to `code_for_2` and `code_for_3`. But it seems that it's really hard to say what happens under the hood in `list(map(...))`.

Comment: `map` functions differently. You should have a look at the answers available on similar problems: [**1**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245465/9209546), [**2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/9209546), [**3**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349900/9209546), [**4**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11616687/9209546).