# parsing a panda dataframe column from a dictionary data form into new columns for each dictionary key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, parsing

In python 3, pandas. Imagine there is a dataframe df with a column x

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
[
{'x':'{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}'},
{'x':'{"a":"2","b":"3","c":"4"}'}
]
)
```

The column x has data which looks like a dictionary. Wonder how can I parse them into a new dataframe, so each key here becomes a new column?

The desired output dataframe is like

```
x,a,b,c
'{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}',1,2,3
'{"a":"2","b":"3","c":"4"}',2,3,4
```

None of the solution in this post seems to work in this case

[parsing a dictionary in a pandas dataframe cell into new row cells (new columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39640936/parsing-a-dictionary-in-a-pandas-dataframe-cell-into-new-row-cells-new-columns)

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(df.loc[:,'x'].values.tolist())

print(df1)
```

## result the same dataframe. didn't separate the column into each key per column

Any 2 cents?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also map `json.loads` and convert to a dataframe like;

```
import json
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['x'].map(json.loads).tolist(),index=df.index)
print(df1)
```

---

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
```

this tests to be faster than evaluating via `ast` , below is the benchmark for 40K rows:

```
m = pd.concat([df]*20000,ignore_index=True)

%%timeit
import json
df1 = pd.DataFrame(m['x'].map(json.loads).tolist(),index=m.index)
#256 ms ± 18.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
import ast
df1 = pd.DataFrame(m['x'].map(ast.literal_eval).tolist(),index=m.index)
#1.32 s ± 136 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
import ast
df1 = pd.DataFrame(m['x'].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist(),index=m.index)
#1.34 s ± 71.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Can you test `pd.DataFrame([json.loads(x) for x in df['x']], index=m.index)` ?

Comment: @jezrael [map is a tad bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616599/python-list-comprehensions-vs-map) , : `312 ms ± 7.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Comment: hmmm, I got `%timeit pd.DataFrame([json.loads(x) for x in m['x']], index=m.index)
206 ms ± 1.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(m['x'].map(json.loads).tolist(),index=m.index)
210 ms ± 11.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: a bit faster `list comprehension`

Comment: @jezrael okay  my tests gives anyways the idea of the answer is use json loads for performance :) now you have added it too in your answer ..  Great..!!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Really appreciate it. Learning a lot! @anky_91

Answer (score 1):

Because string repr of dictionaries is necessary convert values to `dictionaries`:

```
import ast, json

#performance for repeated sample data, in real data should be different
m = pd.concat([df]*20000,ignore_index=True)

In [98]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([json.loads(x) for x in m['x']], index=m.index)
206 ms ± 1.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

#anky_91 solution    
In [99]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(m['x'].map(json.loads).tolist(),index=m.index)
210 ms ± 11.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [100]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(m['x'].map(ast.literal_eval).tolist(),index=m.index)
903 ms ± 12.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [101]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(m['x'].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist(),index=m.index)
893 ms ± 2.15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
print(df1)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
```

Last for append to original:

```
df = df.join(df1)
print(df)
                           x  a  b  c
0  {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}  1  2  3
1  {"a":"2","b":"3","c":"4"}  2  3  4
```